# Prevent JS from messing with my media-specific stylesheet

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I have a div `#example` and a button `#toggle`. When you click on `#toggle`, `#example` is hidden via javascript. When you click again it is shown.

I also have stylesheet for mobile devices that hides both elements for screen size smaller than 500px.

The problem is: I click `#toggle` twice, then resize my browser to < 500px. And then it shows `#example`, despite the style rule. The problem is that javascript overrides this rule.

How can I solve this?

```
<style media="all and (max-width: 500px)">
  #example, #toggle {
    display: none;
  }
</style>

<div id="example">
  Example div
</div>
<button id="toggle" onclick="toggle()">
  Show/Hide
</button>

<script>
  shown = true;
  function toggle() {
    if (shown) {
      document.getElementById("example").style.display="none";
      shown = false;
    }
    else {
      document.getElementById("example").style.display="block";
      shown = true;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution is simple

try to add a class e.g. `is-hidden` instead of changing styles in JS.
Here is the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/70djv1Lu/

This is the best practise, because the CSS code should be in the css file.